# AWS Lambda (NodeJS) throws error when connecting RDS by Sequelize

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

Base on [aws-serverless-express](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express) repository on Github. I've made a connection to AWS RDS in order to CRUD data. I'm using Sequelize for ORM.
I've tested on local, actions work perfectly. But when it's deployed on AWS Lambda the error was thrown at **Sequelize initialization** (without it works normally)

**Sequelize initial**

```
const database = new Sequelize('databasename', 'root', 'password', {
  host: 'XXXXXX.XXXXXX.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
  port: 3306,
  logging: console.log,
  maxConcurrentQueries: 100,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: 'Amazon RDS',
  },
  pool: { maxConnections: 5, maxIdleTime: 30 },
  language: 'en',
});
```

**Error logs was got from CloudWatch:**

```
module initialization error: Error
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:662:20)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/mysql2/lib/packets/ssl_request.js:3:23)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at /var/task/mysql2/lib/packets/index.js:4:16
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/mysql2/lib/packets/index.js:3:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

I fear error throws cause SSL connection problem, but I don't know how to figure out.

**Below is my config on RDS MySql instance:**

> Network & Security
>
> > Security group: default
> >
> > > Inbound:
> > >
> > > > Type: All trafic
> > > >
> > > > Protocol: All
> > > >
> > > > Port Range: All
> > > >
> > > > Source: sg-3c941877 (default)
> > >
> > > Outbound:
> > >
> > > > Type: All trafic
> > > >
> > > > Protocol: All
> > > >
> > > > Port Range: All
> > > >
> > > > Destination: 0.0.0.0/0
> >
> > Public accessibility: Yes
>
> Database options
>
> > IAM DB authentication: Disabled

In AWS Lambda I also added **AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole** Policy

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: Did you place the Lambda function inside the VPC? Also, please show the actual security group rules assigned to the RDS instance, not just the name of the security group.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for your quick reply to my question. I'm newbie with AWS. 
I checked Lambda function's network setting. Currently it hasn't been assigning to VPC. If I set lambda function shall it work for me? 
Security Group rules I edited i description. Please check it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As your suggestion, I also update Network setting in AWS Lambda. With VPC default. Subnets: subnet-0e03d869 (172.31.0.0/20) | us-east-1b
subnet-a64199fa (172.31.32.0/20) | us-east-1a
Security Groups: sg-05f4b536db1d24b0f (rds-launch-wizard)
sg-3c941877 (default)